# How do I make a UISwitch under iOS 7 not take the background colour of the view behind it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uiswitch

It looks like this whenever off:

[image]

While I'd prefer more of a grey background. Do I really have to use a UIImageView?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is how I changed the fill color of my iOS7 UISwitch.

First you need to import QuartzCore.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then set the background color and round the UISwitch's corners.

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 31.0)];
mySwitch.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
mySwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0; // you must import QuartzCore to do this.
[self addSubview:mySwitch];
```

This will give you a UISwitch with a custom off (background) color.

Hope this helps someone:)

Comment: The day they change the shape of the switch your solution will not look fine.

Comment: The day they will change the shape of the switch I will have to recompile the app with the new SDK and then I'll change it.

Answer (score 17):

You can set the `setOnTintColor` property of your `UISwitch` to the color you desire.

Comment: This refers to when it's off.

Comment: For me, this setting refers to when the switch is on. e.g.: [usePatternsSwitch setOnTintColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor]];

Comment: Down vote, because this doesn't answer the question at all. The question is referring to the off state.

Answer (score 6):

You can also set this for the switch in Interface Builder. Just set the background colour of the `UISwitch` to whatever colour you want (white, in the example below), then set a User Defined Runtime Attribute of `layer.cornerRadius = 16`:

[image]

Comment: Just extra thanks for pointing that properties may be set with User Defined list, not just in code.

Answer (score 4):

There's no API support for changing the off fill color of a `UISwitch`.

Adjusting the `tintColor` will only affect the outline, and adjusting the `backgroundColor` will affect the whole frame, including the parts outside the rounded bounds.

You either have to place a properly shaped opaque `UIView` behind it or - easier - use a custom open source implementation, such as [MBSwitch](https://github.com/mattlawer/MBSwitch), which allows you to set the off fill color.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an image as background, using the [UIColor colorWithPatternImage];

```
mySwitch.onTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toggle-bg-on"]];
mySwitch.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toggle-bg-off"]];
```

Comment: Very useful! Better to add swift version too.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Barry Wyckoff solution : set tint color also

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 51.0, 31.0)];
mySwitch.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
mySwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0; // you must import QuartzCore to do this.
mySwitch.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self addSubview:mySwitch];
```